# How can I PUT data into nested JSON in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, put, angular-services

I have this JSON file.

```
{mood: [ {

"id":"1",
"text": "Annoyed",
"cols": 1, 
"rows": 2, 
"color": "lightgreen",
"route":"/angry",

"musics": [
  {
  "id": "0",
  "name": "English- Heaven's Peace",
  "image": "images/music.png",
  "link": "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPfXrbtn3EgleopO8DiEdsNKgqYZZSEKF",
  "descpription": "Tunes that soothe your pained soul",
  "reviews": [
      {                   
           "name": "abc",
           "rating": 4,
           "review": "energetic",
           "date": ""
      }
  ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "English- Hell's Fire",
   "image": "images/music.png",
   "link": "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPfXrbtn3EgmZitRQf1X1iYwWW_nUF44L",
   "descpription": "Beats that match the ones of your heart",
   "reviews": [
       {                   
            "name": "abc",
            "rating": 3.5,
            "review": "energetic",
            "date": ""
       }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "2",
   "name": "Hindi",
   "image": "images/music.png",
   "link": "",
   "descpription": "",
   "reviews": [
       {                   
            "name": "abc",
            "rating": 4,
            "review": "energetic",
            "date": ""
       }            
   ]     
  },
  {
   "id": "3",
   "name": "Punjabi",
   "image": "images/music.png",
   "link": "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPfXrbtn3Egnntch2thUO55YqPQgo4Qh7",
   "descpription": "",
   "reviews": [
       {                   
            "name": "abc",
            "rating": 4,
            "review": "energetic",
            "date": ""
       }            
   ]     
   },
  {
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mix and Match",
   "image": "images/music.png",
   "link": "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPfXrbtn3EglN5LVTETqH3ipRLfXmY6MB",
   "descpription": "",
   "reviews": [
       {                   
            "name": "abc",
            "rating": 5,
            "review": "energetic",
            "date": ""
       }            
   ]     
  }
  ]
 }]
 }`
```

I have created a service that should update any changes in the moods section.

```
putMood(mood: Mood): Observable<Mood> {
const httpOptions ={
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
};
return this.http.put<Mood>(baseURL + 'moods/' + mood.id, mood, httpOptions)
.pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
}
```

And a submit function that should put my newly entered review in the reviews section of my json file under musics section.

```
onSubmit(){
this.review = this.reviewForm.value;
this.review.date = new Date().toISOString();
this.music.reviews.push(this.review);
this.moodservice.putMood(this.mood)
.subscribe(mood => {
this.mood=mood;
},
errmess => {this.mood = null; this.errMess = <any>errmess;});
 }
```

Using this service and function my review is not uploaded to JSON file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: There is no console error for it, It displays successful put but does not get updated in the json file